# SpEL - parseExpression performance

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

As a part of my project, I am implementing a rule engine based on `SpEL` and I am trying to make is as efficient as possible. Basically, the engine consists of persisted conditions in `SpEL` syntax. When an input needs to be evaluated, I query the DB for relevant rules - `SpEL` expressions, which are run on an `EvaluationContext` containing the input objects.

I am already using an Ehcache in the application so I wanted to make use of caches in this service as well. `EvaluationContext` caching is out of question, since the input is different for each request. Caching DB queries is also not that easy because a specific date is a part of the query - different rules are valid in different time.

I thought about caching parsed `Expression` objects but I have no idea how expensive is to parse an `Expression` from `String` and whether the time saved avoiding `Expression` parsing even makes up for having to query the cache through `Spring`.

Does anybody know whether it is efficient to use a cache to store parsed `Expression` objects?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on the complexity of the expressions, but I would expect the cache to be worthwhile in all except maybe the simplest of expressions.

Why don't you just run some perf tests?

**EDIT**

> `EvaluationContext` caching is out of question, since the input is different for each request.

You can generally reuse an evaluation context; just pass the root object into the expression along with the context to `getValue()` instead of storing it in the context.

```
Object getValue(EvaluationContext context, Object rootObject) throws EvaluationException;
```

One exception to that, though, is if you need different `#variables` for each evaluation.

Comment: @Tomas, were you able to achieve any performance improvement with SpEL, I am also requiring to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpEL compilation for further optimization.

Take a look at SpEL compilation and Compiler Configuration part in the official documentation of SpEL:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-spel-compilation